# javascript sum input of type text

Tags: javascript, html

i was trying to sum 2 input of type text(I've already a function that allows only floats so the format isn't a problem) and i don't know why it keeps returning a NaN and how to fix it. Can anyone help me?
html:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="num1"/>
    <p2>+</p2>
    <input type="text" id="num2"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Calc" onclick="calc()"/>
    <p2 id="res"></p2>
</form>
```

javascript:

```
function calc() {
    var res;
    //...
    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML=res;
}
```

Comment: Show the code of `calc()`.

Comment: That part `//...` is where it is going wrong ;)

Comment: Clicking on a submit button submits the form and reloads the page.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compute the sum as follows:

```js
function calc() {
    var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num1").value);
    var b = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num2").value);
    var res = a + b

    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = res.toString();
}
```

Comment: Don't post an answer until they update the question, so you can actually see what they're doing wrong.

Comment: `stopPropagation` has nothing to do with stopping form submission.

Comment: You need to change the HTML to call it as `calc(event)`

Comment: Can I parse a localStorage Item in the same way?